# Trying to get banner to float over box and hang over

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a banner image to sit over a white box with text in it. I want the banner image to float over and hang off each edge, not be constrained to the size of the box div.

I have tried making the banner an image and positioning it absolutely, but that did't provide a good result. The page is designed to be responsive, and while the other elements shrunk in side accordingly, the image remained large.

Attached is an image of what I am trying to achieve with the banner. Everything is coded, it's just the banner that I cannot get right.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you, [image]Nick

Comment: Please include the code that you have so we can help you out.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to paste an entire sheet of code and I am not 100% sure what the relevant parts were. I guess what I am trying to figure out is how to code the white box so it sits relative to the banner div, while maintaining responsiveness.

Comment: "how to code the white box so it sits relative to the banner div".... You don't...you position the banner relative to the div not the other way round.

Comment: We need to start with an HTML basis, because this code represents a time to design and adjust according to your responsiveness requirement. This for sure it represents a worktime, and StackOverflow is not meant to adress some work but to help in a/several specific issues. Please add the relevant code by creating a sample of your issue.

Comment: Try pasting your code in to http://jsfiddle.net ; Save it and post the url with your question. It will allow us to see your code and change parts of it easily.

Comment: Thank you for all of the feedback... here is the jfiddle with the code.\https://jsfiddle.net/9hk8n7mn/

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Apply a `position:relative` to the `banner` and the `whitebox`
2. Move the top of the `banner` downwards (using a positive `px` value)...
3. (Optionally) move the top of the `whitebox` upwards (using a negative `px` value)

See example:

```css
.whitebox, .banner {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner {
width: 360px;
height: 45px;
border: 1px solid rgba(191,191,191,1);
}

.whitebox {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid rgba(127,127,127,1);
}

.banner {
top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
</div>

<div class="whitebox">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rounin for your code help. The problem with this solution seems to be that when the box changes size due to responsiveness, the banner is no longer centered and in position with the white box. It works fine in dekstop, widescreen mode, but not when the screen size goes down.

Comment: Are you using `@media queries` to dynamically update the `width`s of the `.banner` and the `.whitebox`? Or (alternatively), are you declaring the `width`s of the `.banner` and the `.whitebox` using percentages?